# Symfony2 : datatransformer for child object

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have Category hasMany Product relation.
Product entity has `name` and `price` columns.

The problem:

I want to edit Category entity with its `collection` of Product entities using data transformers. For example:

Edit form is empty. I click on "add product", javascript would call ajax and new Product `will` be created. That newly created product has `id` that will be injected into the main form (as hidden), together with field for `name` and `price`.

So I need transformer that will understand the hidden ID and edit name and price on that object.

What I have is kinda big code and Symfony tries to create new object.

NOTE:

I am aware how to work with collections but my real relation is not as in this example and javascript/ajax must create new Product.

Comment: Why do you need this ID to be hidden in your page? If your entities and relations are setup the right way, you just post your data and persist/flush the objects.

Comment: Just trust me on this :)  The relation in question is image that is uploaded via ajax (looks like FB uploader), controller will resize that file, create another one that is thumbnail and save to DB. image_widget will display thumbnail version of that image.